# AnyLogic - unresolved reference to database, although paths deleted

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In my model, agents are read in the source block from an Excel file. I have renewed this Excel file and the path.
The model now works fine, but there are 3 errors during the build. The model is executable despite these 3 errors.

The 3 errors are unresolved reference from this one Excel file. (1.+2. error @ source: interarrival time, 3. error @ source: entitiesPerArrival).

When I search my model with cmd+F for the individual references, I find 1 reference per problem in the workspace, but it is not shown to me. It seems like this reference still exists somewhere, but I don't know where. Neither in the simulation class nor in the dependencies of the model is anything to be found.

Does anyone have an idea how I can update the paths or where I can delete the old reference?

Comment: Some screenshots would help, especially show the "References" tab expanded within your Projects view and the database properties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely (without any further info) is that you have the offending code in the properties of an 'unused' Source block mode (e.g., you changed the "Arrivals defined by" from "Arrival table in database" to something else, and the offending code is in the "Arrival table in database" specific properties which are no longer visible).

AnyLogic still tries to build this code even though its unused and inactive. (It's really a quite annoying bug which has been there for years.) So try temporarily changing the mode back and check/delete any code defined there. (In some cases AnyLogic won't allow you to 'clear' the code so in the worst case you need to recreate the Source block with just the newest properties and remove the old one.)

BTW I also suspect when you say 'read from Excel' you mean Excel imported to the AnyLogic database and used (via queries in block properties) from there, but that's not really relevant if the root cause is what I think it is.

Comment: Hey Stuart, thanks for the help. This solved the problem. What an annoying bug!